# Gradle build fails on OpenShift when run through Jenkins

Tags: linux, jenkins, gradle, openshift

I have set-up Jenkins on OpenShift which reads a private repository from Github.com. It can successfully download the git repository but fails to build it. I get the below message in log.

`FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "gradle"`

Now, basically it's not able to find gradle on the machine. I have gradle available under `data` directory under `app-root`. I have also configured it under `.bash_profile` available under the `data` directory. But still it's not able to pick those changes.

The problem is I need to set Gradle before the build is run. My question is where in OpenShift is the right place to set such configuration. In a typical linux box it would be `$USER_HOME/.bash_profile` but that in OpenShift is denied.

Thanks again for your time.

Comment: If you login as the jenkins user (via e.g. SSH), are you able to successfully run `gradle` manually?  Note that the "standard" way to run Gradle is using the [*Gradle wrapper*](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html), which means you don't need a local installation of Gradle at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to answer my own question here. The problem was it was not able to find Gradle and hence failed when Jenkins issued `gradle clean build`. The solution was to install a Gradle plugin through `Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Gradle Installations`

Once a Gradle installation is available then select that installation by going to the configuration page of your project. Build again and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you selected a "free-style software project" in Jenkins' config panel.

Then you should be able to call arbitrary command to "build" your software project.

- https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-ShellScriptsandWindowsBatchCommands

I recommend you to write a shell script which sets up all the necessary environment variables such as PATH and JAVA_HOME and just call it from Jenkins' "Execute shell" > "command" field.

Answer (score 0):

try the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12484378/1920536.
It worked for me

Or, you can do as follow:
Download gradle ( http://gradle.org/downloads),
unpack it to,
in your Jenkins, go Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Gradle Installations
and add as below

[image]