# Jenkins Ionic build cannot find Gradle

Tags: android, powershell, jenkins, gradle, ionic-framework

It´s been a couple of days trying to build Ionic app with Jenkins, tried different fix approached, and failed every single time, so I´ll appreciate your help.

Version stack:
NODE: v6.10.3
Ionic: v3.3.0
Cordova: v7.0.1 
Gradle: 3.5

```
Environmental variables
ANDROID_HOME
JAVA_HOME
PATH = c:\Gradle\bin 'I read about this and the page suggested to use c:\Gradle\bin\.gradle\3.5 but is not been recognized'
```

I'm able to build locally but when trying to build from Jenkins using same commands on Powershell I got the following error

> ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Integration\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
>       JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131
>       Error: Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
>       or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle 
>       in your path, or install Android Studio

I already tried the following fixes:

- Reinstall Android SDK
- Reinstalling Ionic and cordova globally
- Using Jenkins Gradle

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9082477/755666 seems to address the same issue.

Comment: Hi Steven, look like it, but that fix is not working for me

Comment: I had to install an older SDK manually before to get something similar working, due to a bug in the release, but I believe that has been corrected since then.

Answer (score 0):

The same here. I think something changed in ionic framework, my ionic info is:
global packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils : 1.4.0
Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1
Ionic CLI        : 3.4.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.8
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.4.0
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.1
Cordova Platforms               : android 6.2.3
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.4.2
```

System:

```
Node       : v6.11.0
OS         : Windows 10
Xcode      : not installed
ios-deploy : not installed
ios-sim    : not installed
npm        : 5.0.4
```

But my other app with

```
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.1.0
```

works fine.
This is the first app started under Ionic 3.4