# jenkins gradle deploy - why .gradle foler owned by root?

Tags: jenkins, gradle, build, permissions

I am trying to deploy a spring boot project via `jenkins`.

However, when jenkins build, it failed to create sub folder inside of `.gradle` folder.

here is stacktrace :

```
org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceCreationException: Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:797)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:748)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:574)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:623)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:761)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:747)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:574)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:623)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:761)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:747)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:574)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:623)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.doGet(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:344)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:325)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.doNewInstance(DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.java:151)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.newInstance(DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.java:96)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:50)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceCreationException: Could not create service of type CrossBuildFileHashCache using BuildSessionScopeServices.createCrossBuildFileHashCache().
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:797)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:748)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:574)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:623)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:761)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:747)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:574)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:623)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.doGet(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:344)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:329)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ParentServices.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1111)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$CachingProvider.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:970)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$CompositeProvider.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1034)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext$4.apply(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1356)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext$4.apply(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1353)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext.getServiceProvider(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1297)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext.find(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1285)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.bind(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:722)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.prepare(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:642)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$OwnServices.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:465)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$CachingProvider.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:970)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$CompositeProvider.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1034)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext$4.apply(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1356)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext$4.apply(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1353)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext.getServiceProvider(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1297)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext.find(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1285)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.bind(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:722)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.prepare(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:642)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$OwnServices.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:465)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$CachingProvider.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:970)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$CompositeProvider.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1034)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext$4.apply(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1356)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext$4.apply(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1353)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext.getServiceProvider(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1297)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext.find(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1285)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.getServiceProvider(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:350)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.doGet(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:341)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:325)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.BuildScopeServices.defaultScriptPluginFactory(BuildScopeServices.java:301)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory(BuildScopeServices.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.invoke(ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:795)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Failed to create parent directory '/var/jenkins_home/workspace/ice-core2/.gradle/4.0-milestone-2' when creating directory '/var/jenkins_home/workspace/ice-core2/.gradle/4.0-milestone-2/fileHashes'
    at org.gradle.util.GFileUtils.mkdirs(GFileUtils.java:317)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:54)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:30)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory.doOpen(DefaultCacheFactory.java:89)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory.open(DefaultCacheFactory.java:63)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheRepository$PersistentCacheBuilder.open(DefaultCacheRepository.java:123)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CrossBuildFileHashCache.<init>(CrossBuildFileHashCache.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.BuildSessionScopeServices.createCrossBuildFileHashCache(BuildSessionScopeServices.java:208)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.invoke(ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:795)
    ... 100 more
```

As you can see, it tried some `milestone` folder inside of the `.gradle` folder.

I do not know why only `.gradle` folder is owned by `root`, when I command `ls -al`.

How to make jenkins owns `.gradle` folder.
I have tried add `chown -R jenkins:jenkins .gradle`, but it turns out `operation is not permitted`.

How can I change the owner of `.gradle` in jenkins settings?

================= Edit =========================

I read other posts and do some tries. However till now, none of those works for me.

I found out maybe jenkins version can be a matter.

I am using Jenkins version `2.46.2`.

I have no gradle settings in `System Configuration`, but it is in `Global Tool Configuration`. Have 2 gradle settings here `2.14.1`, `3.5` with auto installation.

I am using `GradlePlugin 1.26`.

Comment: Please check this link, possible duplicate, might be helpful                            https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646762/cannot-run-program-gradle-in-jenkins

Comment: @PeaceIsPearl I read that post after you replied, but it is still not working for me. For others, I put some more information to original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not figure out why `.gradle` is owned by `root`.
However, found way to build.

- goto jenkins workspace, `chown -R jenkins:jenkins .gradle`
- access to jenkins in browser
- build

---

An Edit.

In an alternative way, you could give sudoer authority to user `jenkins`.

```
# I am In devian Linux 8

$ > apt-get update
$ > apt-get upgrade
$ > apt-get install sudo
$ > echo 'jenkins ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL' >> /etc/sudoers
```

I think it is enough to close. 
If you got better way to do this, reply below. Thanks.